# edit chart data in powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I would like to edit the values of a chart within a powerpoint file. I can't seem to find the appropriate methods like .Range and .Cell anywhere.

```
 ActivePresentation.Slides(sl).Shapes(sh).Chart.DataTable
```

does not seem to have all the methods in the conventional DataTable method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(sl).Shapes(sh).Chart.ChartData
    .Activate
    .Workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "test_data"
    .Workbook.Close
End With
```

Comment: +1. Once you've activated the `ChartData`, you're basically dealing with Excel, and a `ListObject` representing the chart's data.

Comment: Is it important to activate `ChartData`? I was able to change cell values without this (Excel 2013).