# Automatically Extending/Shorten Excel Chart Series' Ranges in PPT slides

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a power point presentation of 60 slides with trend data.Each slides has multiple line chart. I am now manually updating/adjusting data source for latest 25 months (e.g. Aug 15 - Aug 17, and next time Sept 15 to Sept 17 ). I always needs to show 25 months of data in each chart.

Months variables are in columns and I have data since March 2007. Is there a way to automate this with a VBA macro to adjust data source with current set up.

Btw, data is not linked to any Excel work book. Data is updated each month for each slide manually in a new month column.

Thanks for your help.

Example of a Line chart that I am talking:
[image: Example of a Line chart that I am talking]

Comment: Best and easiest way to achieve constant automatic refresh of ppt is to create Excel Workbook and link it to PPT. It takes a bit more time to set it up, but when you are finished, your PPT will update with a click of a button.

Comment: Agree with the above. Alternatively, try looking at this this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526566/edit-chart-data-in-powerpoint.

My first reaction, however, would be to question whoever is making you do this. Surely people would be able to use their time better doing something other than looking at 60 slides of multiple charts showing old data?