# Changing data source of chart in powerpoint vba

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have a bar Chart in PowerPoint and want to select the row (Category 1 - 4, see Screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuG4.png)) depending on my selection in the ComboBox.
This is my Code so far:

```
  Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  With SlideShowWindows(1).View


    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Category 1"

        Case "Category 2"

        Case Else

    End Select

End With
End Sub
```

I have no idea how to select source data when there is no seperate Excel-Sheet. There is just the "Excel-Sheet" in PowerPoint which is generated when inserting the Diagramm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart is contained in a `Shape` object, and you can access the source data through `Shape.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1)`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526683/9245853) proposes.

I understood by your question that you want the chart to only display the Category selected. You can *hide* the rows you don't want to be displayed in the source data, and they will be hidden in the chart.

This populates `ComboBox1` with Categories 1-4.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    With ComboBox1
        If .ListCount = 0 Then
            .AddItem "Category 1", 0
            .AddItem "Category 2", 1
            .AddItem "Category 3", 2
            .AddItem "Category 4", 3
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And then you can hide the rows you don't want displayed with something like this.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim shp As Shape: Set shp = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("Chart 3") ' Change to your chart name here
    Dim rw As Integer, j As Integer 

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Category 1"
            rw = 2
        Case "Category 2"
            rw = 3
        Case "Category 3"
            rw = 4
        Case "Category 4"
            rw = 5
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    For j = 2 To 5
        shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.sheets(1).Rows(j).Hidden = (j <> rw)
    Next j
End Sub
```

*Screenshot*

[image]