# Select new array in powerpoint chart using vba?

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

I have a graph in powerpoint that in his data has a lot of rows and what I want to do is with VBA select just a specific row with VBA, can you help me? Thx!

Comment: Welcome to SO! A screenshot of your graph here would be helpful. Also, what do you want to do once you've selected the row?

Comment: With this new row selected, i want to update the graph. As you can see in the image, i hava a lot of rows to be selected

Comment: So you want the graph to only show one row? What do you mean by "I have a lot of rows to be selected" - are you trying to create multiple graphs, 1 for each row? I'm not sure I understand what you want to do.

Comment: I have to make 22 graphs, what I want to make is a text box in my powerpoint presentation where I can write the bus number so that then it can show me the graph for the bus selected, and what I want to know is how can i select with VBA different rows from the ones that are selected right now... And thx for the patience!

Comment: So something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51896129/changing-data-source-of-chart-in-powerpoint-vba/51901642#51901642)? Although this just hides the data, instead of creating a new graph.

Comment: It's not working :( ... The program hides rows but hides to0 the colours that plot the chart... Do you have another solution? thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51901642/9245853):

1. Create and populate `ComboBox1` with `"Bus 1"` to `"Bus 22"`.

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
    Dim i As Integer

    With ComboBox1
        If .ListCount = 0 Then
            For i = 1 To 22
                .AddItem "Bus " & i, i - 1
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

---

2. Then instead of hiding rows, actually change the Source Data of the chart using [`Chart.SetSourceData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.Chart.SetSourceData). To accomplish this:

   - Add a reference to the *Microsoft Excel Object Library* under *Tools > References*.
   - `Find` the `ComboBox1.Value` on the `Worksheet` and get the corresponding Source Data range.
   - Then use `SetSourceData` with a concatenated reference to the `Worksheet`s `Name`, and the `Address` of the Source Data

---

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim shp As Shape: Set shp = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.Shapes("Chart 5") ' Change to your chart name
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, dataRng As Excel.Range
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet: Set ws = shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1)

    With ws
        Set rng = .Cells.Find(ComboBox1.Value)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            ' Data rng starts 1 column to the right and spans 2 rows
            Set dataRng = .Range(rng.Offset(, 1), rng.End(xlToRight).Offset(1))
            shp.Chart.SetSourceData Source:="='" & .Name & "'!" & dataRng.Address, PlotBy:=xlRows
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi again! I'm really grateful that you are still helping me :), but I got two questions:
In the second point that you made: how can I find the combox1.value?
In the third point that you made: the worksheet as no name... is the default excel page from powerpoint, and what is the address of the Source data?
Many thanks, and I hope that you can still help me!

Comment: The code uses the [`Range.Find` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) to find the value. The Source Data address is determined dynamically. The worksheet name is just the name of the first worksheet - i.e. `shp.Chart.ChartData.Workbook.Sheets(1).Name`. You can use `Debug.Print` to check the worksheet's Name and the Source Data's address.