# Powerpoint chart combined custom data labels

Tags: powerpoint

The attached image shows two different charts. The top chart has labels with the values associated with each bar. The bottom chart shows those same values, and adds the suffix to the number ie. "rd", "st", "nd", etc.

I am having trouble replicating the bottom chart. The closest I can get is labels that say "th, 7" or "st, 1". I produced that via the "Format Data Labels" tab: checked off "value from cells" and selected the range of suffixes in the Excel sheet (pop-out) AND also checking off the box for "value".

The second image attached contains the chart source data in the connected Excel sheet.

Any suggestions on how to get the labels to say "7th" instead of "th, 7" ?

[Chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWvqQ.png)

[Excel Data Source for chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fmkbg.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few columns, and you don't anticipate the data to change, it may be easiest to manually relabel the columns in powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple PowerPoint presentation with a blank slide and save it as pp_HelloWorld.pptx

Add the following VBA procedure

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbHelloWorld()
    MsgBox "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

to a module in this presentation and save it as pp_HelloWorld.pptm

Close and reopen this presentation pp_HelloWorld.pptm and the macro will work from the Developer > Macros > Run option

Add the following user defined function udfDate1st2nd3rd

```
Public Function udfDate1st2nd3rd(sDayNumber As String) As String
    udfDate1st2nd3rd = "****"
    If sDayNumber = "1" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "1st"
    If sDayNumber = "2" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "2nd"
    If sDayNumber = "3" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "3rd"
    If sDayNumber = "4" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "4th"
    If sDayNumber = "5" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "5th"
    If sDayNumber = "6" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "6th"
    If sDayNumber = "7" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "7th"
    If sDayNumber = "8" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "8th"
    If sDayNumber = "9" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "9th"
    If sDayNumber = "10" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "10th"
    If sDayNumber = "11" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "11th"
    If sDayNumber = "12" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "12th"
    If sDayNumber = "13" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "13th"
    If sDayNumber = "14" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "14th"
    If sDayNumber = "15" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "15th"
    If sDayNumber = "16" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "16th"
    If sDayNumber = "17" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "17th"
    If sDayNumber = "18" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "18th"
    If sDayNumber = "19" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "19th"
    If sDayNumber = "20" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "20th"
    If sDayNumber = "21" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "21st"
    If sDayNumber = "22" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "22nd"
    If sDayNumber = "23" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "23rd"
    If sDayNumber = "24" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "24th"
    If sDayNumber = "25" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "25th"
    If sDayNumber = "26" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "26th"
    If sDayNumber = "27" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "27th"
    If sDayNumber = "28" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "28th"
    If sDayNumber = "29" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "29th"
    If sDayNumber = "30" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "30th"
    If sDayNumber = "31" Then udfDate1st2nd3rd = "31st"
End Function
```

then test the function with this Sub

```
Sub sbTest()
    MsgBox udfDate1st2nd3rd(Mid("Series 1", 8, 1)) & " Series"
End Sub
```

Add a chart to the Powerpoint Presentation with this code from

[Creating a chart in powerpoint using VBA only without embedded excel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066356/creating-a-chart-in-powerpoint-using-vba-only-without-embedded-excel-data)

```
Sub sbAddChartSlide()

    Dim pre As Presentation
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim ser As Series

    Set pre = ActivePresentation
    Set sld = pre.Slides.Add(Index:=pre.Slides.Count + 1, Layout:=ppLayoutBlank)
    Set cht = sld.Shapes.AddChart(-1, xlColumnClustered).Chart
    Set ser = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    ser.XValues = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
    ser.Values = Array(2.4, 3.2, 5.7, 12.67)
    
End Sub
```

Use the following code to change the series label from "Series 1" to "1st Series"

```
Sub sbChgSerTxt()
    
    Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim cht As PowerPoint.Chart
    Dim wkb As Object
    Dim xl As Object
    Dim strText1 As String
    Dim strText2 As String
    Set pre = ActivePresentation
    
    For Each sld In pre.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.HasChart Then
                Set cht = shp.Chart
                cht.ChartData.Activate
                cht.Refresh
                Set wkb = cht.ChartData.Workbook
                Set xl = wkb.Application
                wkb.Activate
                wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
                strText1 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")
                If InStr(1, strText1, "Series") Then
    '               MsgBox "series found!!!"
                    strText2 = udfDate1st2nd3rd(Mid(strText1, 8, 1)) & " Series"
                    wkb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") = strText2
                Else
                    MsgBox "series NOT found"
                End If
                cht.ChartData.Activate
                cht.Refresh
                wkb.Close (0)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    xl.Quit
End Sub
```

This works on Windows 10 with Office 365