# Find and Replace Chart Labels Variable not defined Error

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking to replace some x-axis values ('Q2 2023' with 'Q3 2023') in about 20 PowerPoint slides for 9 presentations. I found a macro online that seemed to have worked for a lot of people, but I keep getting variable errors.

I have this error now:

Variable not defined on

```
Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts. = False
```

Originally, I did not have the following in the macro, but I kept getting a 'Variable Not Defined Error on xlWhole.

```
Dim Wb As Object
Dim Ws As Object

Set Wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet
```

I thought setting the workbooks/worksheets as objects would fix it.

Does anyone have thoughts on this?

This is the current state of the macro:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub findAndReplaceChrt()

Dim pptPres As Object
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shpe As Shape
Dim c As Chart

Dim sht As Object
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim listArray As Long

Dim Wb As Object
Dim Ws As Object

Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

fndList = Array("Q2 2023")
rplcList = Array("Q3 2023")


'Make pptPres the ppt active
Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

Set Wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set Ws = Wb.ActiveSheet

'Loop through each sld and check for chart title
For Each sld In pptPres.Slides

    'searches through shapes in the slide
    For Each shpe In sld.Shapes

        'Checks if shape is a Charts and has a Chart Title
        If Not shpe.HasChart Then GoTo nxtShpe

        Set c = shpe.Chart

        If Not c.ChartType = xlPie Then

            ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
            c.ChartData.Activate

            'Loop through each item in Array lists
            For listArray = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

                    Wb.Ws.Cells.Replace What:=fndList(listArray), Replacement:=rplcList(listArray), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

            Next listArray

            c.ChartData.Workbook.Close

        End If

nxtShpe:
    Next shpe

Next sld

End Sub
```

and this is the original version:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub findAndReplaceChrt()

Dim pptPres As Object
Dim sld As Slide
Dim shpe As Shape
Dim c As Chart

Dim sht As Object
Dim fndList As Variant
Dim rplcList As Variant
Dim listArray As Long

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

fndList = Array("Q2 2023")
rplcList = Array("Q3 2023")

'Make pptPres the ppt active
Set pptPres = PowerPoint.ActivePresentation

'Loop through each sld and check for chart title
For Each sld In pptPres.Slides

    'searches through shapes in the slide
    For Each shpe In sld.Shapes

        'Checks if shape is a Charts and has a Chart Title
        If Not shpe.HasChart Then GoTo nxtShpe

        Set c = shpe.Chart

        If Not c.ChartType = xlPie Then

            ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewNormal
            c.ChartData.Activate

            'Loop through each item in Array lists
            For listArray = LBound(fndList) To UBound(fndList)

                    Worksheets(1).Cells.Replace What:=fndList(listArray), Replacement:=rplcList(listArray), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False


            Next listArray

            c.ChartData.Workbook.Close

        End If

nxtShpe:
    Next shpe

Next sld

End Sub
```

Comment: `xlWhole` is a constant defined in the Excel object library, so if your PPT VBA project doesn't have a reference added for that library then `xlWhole` will be flagged as undeclared.

Comment: For clarification - you're running this code in PPT ?

Comment: Because the VBA code for both PowerPoint and Excel, and execute VBA in the PowerPoint VBA environment.
 I would set references to both the PowerPoint and Excel Object Libraries form "Tools>References". And change code to Early bounding such as;
 
    Dim pptPres As Presentation
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application

    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Ws As Excel.Worksheet

Comment: @vbakim updating the references almost worked. It started to run but it gave me an error of "Method 'Worksheets' of object '_Global' failed. 
If not every chart in the presentation has that text, do I need to include an: If listArray = fdnList Then Worksheets... 
End If?

Comment: @TimWilliams ^ really appreciate the help from both of you. this will cut down hours of manual formatting

Comment: `Worksheets` is a method of an Excel `Workbook` object - you need first to get a reference to that.  Look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.chartdata.workbook for guidance on that and https://stackoverflow.com/a/23526683/478884 for a previous post here on a similar topic